# Why does a function with return gives me undefined when I use it inside module export? node.js

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, module-export

I am practicing some module export exercises using a function with a return statement passed inside a module export then to be imported in a new file, it tells me `total` is not defined? why is this happening?

Code:

file 1:

```
// Using Async & Await with MODULE EXPORT.

const googleDat = require('../store/google-sheets-api.js');

//passing a let var from a function to another file
let total = googleDat.addVat(100);
console.log(total);
```

File 2:

```
function addVat(price) {
  let total = price*1.2
  return total
};

module.exports = {
  total
};
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you export a variable that havn't ben initialized AND you didn't exported your function :

```js
function addVat(price) {
  //defining variable with let work only in this scope
  let total = price*1.2
  return total
};

//In this scope, total doesn't exists, but addVat does.

module.exports = {
  total //So this is undefined and will throw an error.
};
```

What you want to do is to export your function, not the result inside.

```js
function addVat(price) {
  return  price * 1.2;
};

module.exports = {
  addVat
};
```

Comment: Man, I think when I am tired I get a bit blind, this helps me thanks, the worst thing was that I was not even calling the right file in the console haha, I was supposed to call the test file.

Answer (score 0):

On file 2, you should be exporting the addVat() function itself and not just its return. Try this one:

```js
exports.addVat = (price) => {
  let total = price*1.2
  return total
};
```